# what is the ratio of a ratio of two variances

Tags: variance, interaction, f-test, ratio

I know that the ratio of two variances leads to an F-test but what of the ratio of two variance ratios? Is there are simple comparable result? Essentially I'm looking for the analogue of an interaction to a t-test (or two group comparison).

Comment: Could you explain how a "ratio of two variance ratios" might be related to a test of interaction?  What application brings you to consider this ratio?

Comment: I have two factors. Factor A causes a decrease in measurement precision that I could quantify by a F-test say. I can also change the overall setup through a second parameter B: different values of B with give different F-tests for the effect of A. The question is is the effect of B on these ratios significant? Measuring by my F-test, is one B better at protecting against the effects of A. If I had differences not ratios, it'd be a difference of differences - an interaction. It's an analogy but most likely does not help.

Comment: I doubt the ratio of variance ratios is relevant to addressing your question.  You can enhance your chances of obtaining useful answers, then, by editing this post to describe the problem you actually face (instead of describing a proposed solution).